# Memory error while working with an Manager and an vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I want to create a Manager that holds multiple objects and has to be used in order to actually create the objects.
The objects hold their information in a smart pointer.
this is how I implemented it:

```
struct Object
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> number;
};

struct Manager
{
    std::vector<Object> objects;
    Object& createObject()
    {
        objects.emplace_back();
        return objects.back();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Manager manager;
    Object& object1 = manager.createObject();

    object1.number = std::make_shared<int>(10);

    for (Object& o : manager.objects)
    {
        std::cout << *o.number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I execute this code I get my expected output: 10

but once I try to create multiple objects like this:

```
Manager manager;
Object& object1 = manager.createObject();
Object& object2 = manager.createObject();

object1.number = std::make_shared<int>(10);
object2.number = std::make_shared<int>(5);

for (Object& o : manager.objects)
{
    std::cout << *o.number << std::endl;
}
```

I get an runtime error in the memory library at this function:

```
void _Decref()
        {   // decrement use count
        if (_MT_DECR(_Uses) == 0)
            {   // destroy managed resource, decrement weak reference count
            _Destroy();
            _Decwref();
            }
        }
```

does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: my error code is not in english but something like access violation while writing at Position 0xDDDDDDE1

Comment: yeah you can't reference to a local variable and use it outside of it's scope.

Comment: do i have to use the manager to correcly change the objects and not use a reference?

Comment: @nullqube it's a local variable to struct not a local to function to it can be referencable

Comment: @Dolfos what is the purpose of calling this with no parameters?  `objects.emplace_back();`

Comment: @OnurA. It dosnt really have a purpose other then me not having to call the contructor like this: objects.push_back(Object());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never a good idea to use vectors of class instances in conjunction with pointers or references to these class instances. Like Bo Persson already correctly answered, these pointers or references tend to become dangling due to the dynamic nature of a `std::vector`: when a `std::vector` grows, it often copies its items to a different memory position, leaving the already existing item references and pointers invalid (dangling).

You can easily avoid that by storing pointers to classes instead of the classes itself.

```
struct Manager
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
    Object& createObject()
    {
        objects.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Object>());
        return *objects.back().get();
    }
};
```

Now `std::vector` may move the `unique_ptr`'s around as it likes - the smart pointers content (raw pointers) and thus also the references never change (except if you willful change or delete them, of course)

Here's an illustration what happens when you use a vector of class instances.
The grey vertical stripes symbolize the memory - the real structure of memory and sizes are ignored here.

[image]

Step 1: You have a vector (symbolized by square brackets) holding a class instance as an item. The memory behind the vector is occupied (reality is a little different, but the image should suffice)

Step 2: You create a reference (or pointer) to your class instance. (green arrow)

Step 3: You add a second class instance to the vector. The vector has no room for its items, and thus have to move its content to another memory position. Your pointer/reference is broken! (red arrow)

And here's an illustration of the pointer solution:

[image]

Step 1: You have a vector again, but now it's a vector of smart pointers. It holds a smart pointer pointing (dark green arrow) to a class instance.

Step 2: You again create a reference (or pointer) to your class instance. (green arrow)

Step 3: You add a second pointer to a class instance to the vector. The vector has no room for its items, and thus has to move its content to another memory position. But this time only the smart pointers are moved, not the class instances itself! Class instance 1 stays at its place, smart pointer 1 still points to class instance 1, your reference stays intact, and everyone stays happy :)

*Additionally*: Apart from being a safe solution, using pointer vectors instead of instance vectors very often also has a performance benefit. `unique_ptr` are very small, nearly always much smaller than the objects they hold pointers to. And so, when `std::vector` has to copy its items to a different memory position, it has lot less work to do if these are only small smart pointers.
On top of that, there are some classes, which have expensive copy constructors (e.g. locking!). All of that can be avoided if the class instance is not copied at all.

Comment: it is still not clear to me a pointer only holds the memory address to the thing its pointing to, so how come the pointer is still pointing to the right memory address after the std::vector messed with the object the pointer was pointing to? or am i understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: Wait please... I'm just creating an illustration which should clarifiy this.

Comment: oh wow, I forgot that only the pointer is being moved on not the object itself. Now it makes sense. Thanks you very much for taking the time to explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

When adding new elements to the vector, you risk that references to the old objects get invalidated.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back where it says:

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.

So after adding `object2`, the reference `object1` might be invalid.

Comment: Thanks you, by using vector::reserve i was able to increase the capacity and it fixed my error.

Comment: Oh noes... that definitely didn't fix your error, Dolfos... it just postponed it to a later time - when the vector is extended again ;) 
Please see my answer for a real fix.

Comment: @user2328447 you are right, thank you, I dont completely understand why its working with your solution, guess i have some homework to do ;)

Comment: Perhaps I can extend the answer a bit, so that the principle becomes clearer... I'll try it.

Comment: @Dolfos, I wrote an article that explains how this works: [C++ std::vector for post-beginners](https://swdevmastery.com/c-stdvector-for-post-beginners-including-real-issues-ive-seen-in-practice-and-surprising-modern-usage-recommendations/). I think you'll benefit from reading it all, but at least check out the "Bug alert!" sections. I will help.